# Invoke pytest from python for current module only

Tags: python, pytest

I know that py.test can test a single module if I do:

```
py.test mod1.py
```

Or, I can invoke pytest inside python:

```
import pytest
pytest.run(['mod1.py'])
```

Can I do it inside python, and let it to run the current module? I guess I can do:

```
import pytest
import os
pytest.main([os.path.basename(__file__)])
```

But wonder whether this is the most "pythonic" way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: The examples you have shown are for a file, but the question you are asking is about module. Please clear what exactly you want

Answer (score 22):

Your versions do not allow passing extra arguments to pytest (e.g. allow `./test_file.py -v`). I tried simply

```
import sys


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pytest.main(sys.argv)
```

and it seems to do the trick. `sys.argv[0]` is the script name (i.e. `__file__`, possibly as a relative path), so it restricts the call to the script, and `sys.argv[1:]` contain extra arguments passed on the command-line.

Any better idea appreciated!